# How to copy List object as pointer to original object

Tags: java, list, copy

I'm fairly new to Java so I hope I'm explaining this scenario correctly.

I'm trying to copy a List object, but want my second copy to point to the same object as the first List object.  The only reason I need two copies is that I need to iterate through each one independently.  I've tried to find a way and have even asked several colleagues, but the only thing that's working is to create another object all together.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Christine

Update:  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

This is how I currently have the lists declared:

```
List monetaryTransactions = null;

//make a copy of the monetary trans list for use when info is needed about a parent transaction
List parentMonetaryTransactions = new ArrayList(monetaryTransactions);

And this is how I'm using them:

  //THE monetaryTransactions LIST IS POPULATED AND THEN.....

  //loop through the monetary transactions list
  for (Iterator iter = monetaryTransactions.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
       monetaryTransaction = (IMonetaryTransaction) iter.next();

      .....

      //if there is a parent transaction get info about that transaction
      if ( monetaryTransaction.getParentBillingTransactionId() != null) {                               
         //get the parent billing trans id of the current monetary transaction
         parentBillingTransId = monetaryTransaction.getParentBillingTransactionId();                                 

     IT'S THIS SECOND SORT AND ITERATION THAT I NEED TO MAKE SURE DOES NOT AFFECT MY OUTTER LOOP'S ITERATION
     Collections.sort(parentMonetaryTransactions, new MonetaryTransactionOriginalProcessDateDescOrderComparator());


         //loop through parent monetary trans list to find the parent transaction
     for (Iterator iter2 = parentMonetaryTransactions.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {
          parentMonetaryTransaction = (IMonetaryTransaction) iter2.next();

             .......
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to explain your actual problem.

Comment: I am trying to understand why you want to iterate both list having same data? If there is a direct reference to those objects then there would be an issue called ConcurrentModificationException which possibly occurs when trying to modify.

Comment: I won't be modifying either list.  I basically need to iterate through the list first evaluating each transaction and then at certain points I may need to iterate through the same list but this time looking for the parent transaction of the transaction I'm working with in the first loop, and I need the ability to sort and manage each iterator independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this piece of code will throw a NullPointerException:

```
List monetaryTransactions = null;

//make a copy of the monetary trans list for use when info is needed about a parent transaction
List parentMonetaryTransactions = new ArrayList(monetaryTransactions);
```

Going further down, why do you need to sort and iterate through the list again? Does each `IMonetaryTransaction` have more than one parent, with different Original Process Dates? Do different transactions share the same ID?

If you have access to the `IMonetaryTransaction` source, it would be cleaner to keep a reference to the parent transaction itself rather than store just the ID. E.g.

```
interface IMonetaryTransaction {
    // This...
    IMonetaryTransaction getParentBillingTransaction();

    // ...rather than this
    long getParentBillingTransactionId();
}
```

But if you can't change this model, and only have a flat list of all transactions, parents mixed in with children, it might be easier (and more efficient) to create a Map of transactions by ID:

```
Map<Long, IMonetaryTransaction> transactions = new HashMap<>();
monetaryTransactions.forEach(txn -> transactions.put(txn.getId(), txn);
```

So that when you need to get the parent of a given transaction, you just need to do this instead of iterating through the entire list again.

```
IMonetaryTransaction parent = transactions.get(txn. getParentBillingTransactionId());
```

Comment: In my first loop I'm looping through the list looking at info about each transaction in the list. In the second instance I want to iterate through again, this time looking for the transaction's parent transaction.  I basically want two instances so I don't affect the iterator in my outter loop.

Comment: OK, but this doesn't really sound like a nested loop so not sure you will have an "outer loop" at all. If you can post some real code for your scenario it might be easier to discuss.

Comment: hi, I've edited my original post to include an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Riaz - sorry for the delayed reponse.  
To your first point where you mentioned a Null Pointer Exception...I should have demonstrated that I was populating the monetaryTransactions list before creating the copy.

Comment: Cont'd....

Secondly, with regard to why I need to sort and iterate through the list again....each transaction has, at most, one parent transaction but on the monetary transaction itself it lists only the parent billing trans id, so later I evaluate whether or not the current transaction has a parent transaction id and if it does I sort by date descending (I'm normally looking for recent transactions so I want to get out as quickly as possible...hence the need to sort)....

Comment: Cont'd.... and loop through all transactions looking for a match on the current transaction's parent billing trans id to another transaction's billing trans id. Once I find the parent trans I need to evaluate specific details about that parent transaction, not just one piece of data so I think that eliminates the use of a hash map, right?

Comment: You should still be able to use the HashMap approach; it allows you to remove the inner loop over the transaction list, which resolves your original question, and it will be quicker on average than iterating through the list, even if the list is sorted by date descending. Once you get the parent transaction from the map, you can do the further checks you need.

Answer (score 1):

You variable reference to the list can be thought of as a pointer to that object's instance. So you can create any arbitrary number of pointers to your list.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> anotherPointer = list;
```

Now anything you with the references `list` and `anotherPointer` will reflect on the object itself.

```
list.add("Hello");
System.out.println(anotherPointer.size()); //Prints 1
```

Comment: This would be a great answer if it used generics properly.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.  Would this structure affect my ability to sort each reference to the list and manage separate iterators?

Comment: @Christine You can have any number of iterators for the object itself. Not sure if that answers your question. All your doing is copying a reference to an object. You can have a million references to the same list, but what you do with one reference will be reflected on the object itself and therefore seen by all other references.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Kon.  I'll play around with the different approaches you mentioned and will see what happens when I'm in the various loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create another `List` object you can use two `int` variables along with the `get(int index)` function to access the `List` at different indices.